# Short story about a man gives up chance to be first on the moon because of danger of becoming sterile

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a sci fi short story about a man who gives up the chance to be the first man to go to the moon.  He is warned that there is a chance that the flight to the moon may make him sterile and chooses to remain on earth and have children.

Comment: I found the story you reminded me of: John Christopher's "Occupational Risk", which I just reread.  Sorry, it's not the one you're looking for. Completely different story, except for the "spacers shouldn't have children" theme.

Answer (score 12):

That is the plot of a William Tenn short story ["The Dark Star"](https://scifistandpoint.wordpress.com/tag/william-tenn/) in the collection "The Wooden Star". The protagonist talks about how for safety's sake, the first astronaut to set foot on the Moon will be sterilized before the trip to avoid radiation affecting any children he fathers on his return; Thus, the narrator notes, becoming immortal one way but losing the very real prospect of immortality through offspring.

The twist? Turns out the radiation risk is exaggerated and proves unnecessary. The narrator doesn't go on this trip and settles down to work on building spacecraft; later, his daughter becomes part of the first Mars mission, and later still his grandson and his wife leave on the first interstellar voyage at the end of the story.

Comment: You're on a run today.

Comment: The story is titled "The Dark Star".

Comment: Please edit the title of the story ("The Dark Star" as in Organic Marble's comment.) into your answer. If the question comes up again, it'll be a lot easier to find the duplicate if the words "The Dark Star" appear in the answer instead of a comment.